# Extracting cookies from $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

This seems like it should be dead simple. I want to use $resource to save() something to the server. The server will respond with a cookie. I need to use that cookie on my next request. Somehow, in the year 2014, it seems that this is literally impossible.

The $resource looks something like this:

```
cartService.factory('AddToCart', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('my-url.com'
        {
            withCredentials: true,
            transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) {
                alert(headersGetter);
            }
        }
    );
}]);
```

First of all, the transformResponse isn't firing at all. I figured I might be able to breakpoint it and look at the backing object... nope.

Second, the only header there seems to be the content-type header. Everything from Date to X-* to transfer-encoding seems to be stripped out.

If I add a success() function to the call, it looks like this:

```
$scope.order = AddToCart.save({}, function(a, b) {
            console.log(a);
            console.log(b('JSESSIONID'));
        });
```

Again, nothing. I'd really appreciate any pointers. If I have to dig into the $http guts just to deal with cookies, I can't help but be confused by the point of this framework.